# for loop drawing to canvas isn't work. Draws string to the first location but not the next

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm working on a dynamic timestable sheet. My first issue is that I want to make sure I can print a string in reportlab at different variables, however my loop isn't working. It prints the string at the first loacation but not at the subsequent ones.

I've tried printing the variable for height and that progressively goes up, so that works and the variable containing the x coordinate is fine too. So I know the loop is looping.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4
from reportlab.platypus import Image
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
import os
#have to register a font first
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Marcellus SC', 'MARCELLUSSC-REGULAR.ttf'))

PDF_FILENAME = "Timestable_File.pdf"
PDF_LOCATION = "C:/Users/BOTTL/Desktop/PDF Python Save/"

FILENAME_AND_LOCATION = os.path.join( PDF_LOCATION, PDF_FILENAME )
FONT_TYPE = "Marcellus SC"
REGULAR_SIZE = 14

COLUMN1 = 42


#Lets the program know where to save the pdf
c = canvas.Canvas(FILENAME_AND_LOCATION, pagesize=letter)
c.setFont(FONT_TYPE,32,leading=None)
c.setFont(FONT_TYPE,REGULAR_SIZE,leading=None)



for i in range (1,11):
    ROW_VAR = 600
    c.drawString(COLUMN1,ROW_VAR,"TEST STRING")
    ROW_VAR =ROW_VAR + i * 20
    i +1
    print(i)
    print (ROW_VAR)







c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Actual result is that it prints one "TEST STRING" at coordinate 42,600

I expected to have a column of 10 versions of this spaced out

Answer (score 0):

You are settings `ROW_VAR` to 600 before you print the `TEST_STRING`. Every loop you run you reset the `ROW_VAR` to 600.

You should define `ROW_VAR` outside the for loop once, so you can update it in the loop.

Something like this should work

```py
ROW_VAR = 600

for i in range (1,11):
    c.drawString(COLUMN1,ROW_VAR,"TEST STRING")
    ROW_VAR = ROW_VAR + i * 20
    i +1
    print(i)
    print (ROW_VAR)
```

Comment: I can absolutely see that now. Think i just had code blindness. Rookie error. Thanks :)